# How do you say "to have an oil change" in German?

Tags: idiom

> Every 3 months i have my car oil changed.

Alle drei Monate lasse ich meinen Wagen Öl wechseln.

In English, you can also say `to have an oil change,` where the word "change" is a gerund, and the word "oil," normally a noun, is used as an adjective. Is there an equivalent German construction.

Comment: I disagree with the downvotes...German is so chock full of idioms that you can often be wrong when you translate literally.

Comment: I clarified the question by asking for the German equivalent (if any) of an English construction, and voted to reopen in its current form.

Comment: @TomAu: thank you for your effort but in this case (where answers exclusively address the oil change rather than the grammar concept) I believe we should wait for another, more general question asking for the German equivalent of "to have sth + done".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`oil change` can be translated as `Ölwechsel`.

You can use it in combiantion with e.g. `vornehmen lassen` (somebody else is doing this for you)

> Alle drei Monate lasse ich einen Ölwechsel vornehmen.

Or of course in combination with `machen` -- done by yourself ....

> Alle drei Monate mache ich einen Ölwechsel

Comment: In my opinion, `machen` is not in any case an indicator that you do it yourself.

Comment: In this case it definitely is.

Comment: @cr0 as machen is quiet general, you are absolut correct -- it would just mean something like `do`. But in my example at least I think it's obious who is going to do the oil change .. ;)

Answer (score 3):

> Alle drei Monate lasse ich einen Ölwechsel machen.

Comment: @Twinkles sorry for the late reponse. Concerning that. Just because OP wants a quick translation, should you give it to him? The goal of this site is to educate learners and provide explanation and reasoning. Just Translating a sentence is off-topic as of our [help/on-topic]. That's why I was missing an explanation in your post.